# How to test whether a variable has been initialized before using it?

Tags: python

So let's say you've got an application with a variable that you will be creating an instance of when you load it independently (ie when you use `if __name__ == '__main__'`).

Also, there is a method that is to be called for when a client imports the application for use within another application.  This method will also instantiate this variable.

What I want to do is test whether the variable has already been instantiated before defining it (so I don't have to go through the creation of the object twice).  My intuition told me to use `if SOME_VARIABLE is not None: #instantiate here` but this yields the error

> local variable 'SOME_VARIABLE'
>   referenced before assignment

What gives?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's an error to access a variable before it is initialized. An uninitialized variable's value isn't None; accessing it just raises an exception.

You can catch the exception if you like:

```
>>> try:
...    foo = x
... except NameError:
...    x = 5
...    foo = 1
```

In a class, you can provide a default value of None and check for that to see if it has changed on a particular instance (assuming that None isn't a valid value for that particular variable):

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = None
    def foo(self):
        if self.bar is None:
            self.bar = 5
        return self.bar
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try `if 'varname' in locals()` (you probably also have to check `globals()`, and maybe some other places), or just read from the variable and catch the `NameError` exception which will be thrown when it doesn't exist.

But if you just want the else-case of `if __name__ == '__main__'`, why not just do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
    myvar = 'as_main'
else:
    myvar = 'as_import'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can test if the variable was initialized in a assertion statement, for example. (a true test, not a handling problems).